# What is wrong in this code: giflib library usage

Tags: c, gif

I have read the giflib usage explanation and wrote the following code:

```
GifFileType *gifFile = DGifOpenFileName("D:\\my.gif00.gif");
DGifSlurp(gifFile);
int h = gifFile->SHeight;
int w = gifFile->SWidth;
int count = gifFile->ImageCount;
GifPixelType *myPixels = new GifPixelType[w]; 

int errcode = DGifGetLine(gifFile, myPixels, 1);
if (errcode == GIF_OK) {
} else {
    PrintGifError();
}
```

As you see there, any file I set into the DGifOpenFileName function as argument results in an error, the PrintGifError() prints out the following message:

GIF-LIB error: #Pixels bigger than Width * Height.

I can't understand what is wrong in my code. what I want is to read the gif file's pixels, Edit them then set back to the gif file. 
Could you help with this issue?

Answer (score 5):

<strike>As far as I can tell, this seems to indicate that you gif file is corrupt.</strike>

The problem is that you shouldn't be using `DGifGetLine()`. The function `DGifSlurp()` reads the entire GIF file into the gifFile structure. Internally, it calls `DGifGetLine()` (and a fair few other things), and by the time it returns, the entire file has been processed. Trying to call `DGifGetLine()` after that doesn't make sense.

This is what dgif_lib.c says about `DGifSlurp()`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 This routine reads an entire GIF into core, hanging all its state info off
 the GifFileType pointer.  Call DGifOpenFileName() or DGifOpenFileHandle()
 first to initialize I/O.  Its inverse is EGifSpew().
*******************************************************************************/
```

Comment: @maximus Was this answer helpful? If so, please consider accepting it. If not, why not?